# spring data not get id annotaion on method

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-rest

When my Entity id annotation on field, it's OK on spring data jpa.

```
public class User {
   @Id
   @Column(name="id")
   Long rid;
   @Column(name="name")
   String name;
}
```

but not work on method...

```
public class User {

   Long rid;

   String name;
   @Id
   @Column(name="id")
   public Long getId() {
       return this.id;
   }
   @Column(name="name")
   public Long getName() {
       return this.name;
   }
}
```

the error message is `PersistentEntity does not have an identifier property!`

why?
I need to set annotation on method, because I want to set association auto.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<Phone> getPhones() {
  return smtpRecords;
}

public void setPhones(Set<Phone> phones) {
  phones.forEach(e -> e.setUser(this));
  this.phones= phones;
}
```

any solution? Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am facing the exact same issue...